# Kotlin: Get file's extension e.g. ".txt"

Tags: java, io, kotlin

Is there a standard way to get the extension of a `File` in Kotlin?

```
File("a/b/file.txt")
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Disclaimer: *This is only available on the JVM.*

You can find very neat extensions on `java.io` classes like `File` in `kotlin.io`. In order to get the file extension, use the following:

```
File("a/b/file.txt").extension
```

This extension property is defined [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/extension.html):

```
public val File.extension: String
        get() = name.substringAfterLast('.', "")
```

Comment: it's called kotlin extension function. Awsome ;)

Comment: Hi, could you explain or give me some clue about the dependence of this method on JVM? I thought JVM is just an executor, it does not and should not affect the availability of a method.

Comment: Kotlin in the JVM reuses the JDK and its capacities such as the File class. This class is not available natively when running Kotlin e.g. natively

Answer (score 0):

This is how you extract file extension from a file Uri in Kotlin

```
val videoExtension =
        (DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(requireContext(), videoUri)?.name ?: "").split('.')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using Kotlin extension!

```
private fun File.isTxTFile(): Boolean = this.extension == "txt"
```